# Automatic sheet size in text label in QGIS

Tags: qgis, labeling, print-composer

I'm in Print Composer and want to develop a template. In that template, I would like to add a text Label which automatically represents the size of the sheet in the format *"Sheet size: 841x1189"*.

There is got to be an expression for that but I can't find it. Can someone recap it for me?

Answer (score 4):

Go with

```
'Sheet size: '||@layout_pageheight ||' x '|| @layout_pagewidth ||' mm'
```

For the future: In any template text field, go to "add expression" and check the bullet point "variables".

Additional input from [csk](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/81764/csk): In order for the formula to work you need to add `[%` in the front and `%]` in the end. Forgot about this, my bad.

So we have:

```
[%'Sheet size: '||@layout_pageheight ||' x '|| @layout_pagewidth ||' mm'%]
```

Comment: This works in the expression builder. To paste it directly into the text label, you need to add `[%` before and `%]` after.